# PostgreSQL amount for each day summed up in weeks

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to find a solution to this challenge all day.

I've got a table:

```
  id   | amount  | type |            date            |              description              | club_id 
-------+---------+------+----------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------
   783 |   10000 |    5 | 2011-08-23 12:52:19.995249 | Sign on fee                           |       7
```

The table has a lot more data than this.

What I'm trying to do is get the sum of amount for each week, given a specific club_id.

The last thing I ended up with was this, but it doesn't work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week, amount FROM club_expenses WHERE club_id = 20 AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) < 10 ORDER BY week 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT week+1, amount FROM t WHERE week < 3
)
SELECT week, amount FROM t;
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but it complains about the UNION ALL.

I'll be off to bed in a minute, so I won't be able to see any answers before tomorrow (sorry).

I hope I've described it adequately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to use the UNION ALL to retrieve a subset of the first part of the query.  That won't work.  You have two options.  The first is to use user defined functions to add behavior as you need it and the second is to nest your WITH clauses.   I tend to prefer the former, but you may be preferring the latter.

To do the functions/table methods approach you create a function which accepts as input a row from a table and does not hit the table directly.   This provides a bunch of benefits including the ability to easily index the output.  Here the function would look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION week(club_expense) RETURNS int LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS $$
    select EXTRACT(WEEK FROM $1.date)
$$;
```

Now you have a usable macro which can be used where you would use a column.  You can then:

```
SELECT c.week, sum(amount) FROM club_expense c
 GROUP BY c.week;
```

Note that the c. before week is not optional.  The parser converts that into week(c).  If you want to limit this to a year, you can do the same with years.

This is a really neat, useful feature of Postgres.

Comment: Thanks!
As far as I can see, this looks exactly like what I need.

I get en error when trying to create the function, though:
return type mismatch in function declared to return integer
DETAIL:  Actual return type is double precision.

So, somethings not completely as it should be :/
I can't see why it should want to return a double precision??

Comment: Ok, I just gave up and used double precision. Now it works.

Next question :)
I need to limit my search to only take the last 15 weeks from now. The problem is when the year changes it starts at week 1. I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: `where c.date >= now()::date - (15 * 7).`  Note that when you cast the now() to date, you can subtract days as an integer expression.  If you need to start on the Sunday before, you can:  where `c.date >= (now()::date - (15 * 7) - extract('dow' from now())::int)`

Comment: Ok, I have this now:  
`CREATE FUNCTION club_expenses_by_week(club_expenses) RETURNS double precision AS $$
    SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM $1.date)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;`  
`SELECT c.club_expenses_by_week, sum(amount) FROM club_expenses c
    WHERE club_id = 20 AND c.date >= now()::date - (15 * 7)
    GROUP BY c.club_expenses_by_week;`  
This gives me:´ club_expenses_by_week |  sum
-----------------------+--------
                    31 |  91708
                    28 |  88963
                    34 |  12421
                    29 |  92403
`  
The weeks (dates) aren't ordered. :/

Comment: If the weeks aren't ordered by date, I might get the data in wrong order if I just order by week (with the year starting at week 1).
I appreciate all your help and I'm sorry for being a bit dense. :)

Comment: Ok, so you have a set of records, such that week(c) is a function of c.date, right?  You also restrict those records such that week(c) means a specific week, and not the same week a year ago, right?  The first is definitional, and the second is in the scope of your where clause.  The records will be ordered *after* grouping, so you can't order by date, you have to order by week.   This is just a sort operation so it is sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Right now the weeks come in as:
31, 28, 34, 29, and so on, in no particular order (as far as I can see). If I order by week, I'll get the right order, except if I was in january/february, where I would have week 1 as the first, where it instead should be the last, after week 52. I need it to be sorted by date, even though I have no date :/ don't know how to go about that. Maybe the function should return a table or something?

Comment: Ah, so I understand.  Yes, you can order by week,  However your wraparound issue will there.  However I would create a separate function for this, namely "week_starting" which would be:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION week_starting(date) returns date language sql immutable as $$
SELECT $1 - EXTRACT('DOW' FROM $1)::int $$; 

You could make this a table method too instead of a date function, but since you may want to use this on now() also, I would recommend making the argument a date.  Then you can group by and order by that instead.

Comment: I'm not following you. Not that you're explaining it badly, just that I'm not that good at sql :)  A friend of mine took a look at it and gave me another solution that works in my case. `SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, sum(amount ) FROM club_expenses WHERE club_id = 20 AND date > now() - interval '32 weeks'  GROUP BY year, week ORDER BY year, week;`  This will give me a result with week, year and amount. Thank you for your help and time. I've learned a lot from what you told me, even though I didn't end up using it. Thanks!